# Is there a single verb that means "to land on the moon"?

Tags: word-request

translate.google.com says that the Italian word "allunare" corresponds to the English phrase "[to] land on the Moon" and, as far as I remind, this is the first time I come across an Italian word that, at least apparently, doesn't have an equivalent or parallel English word.

So, since the verb "allunare" is derived from the noun "luna" (note: al[luna]are) I began the process of thinking as to whether there could be a productive moon-word useable in this case, but answers to a previsious question exclude that one can form verbs like  "moon + particle", and I'm not able to think of another single verb.

If there were one, it had to be something along "moon on" or "moon over", but not.

Therefore, the question is: Is there a verb, made up by a single word, that mean "to land on the moon"?

Comment: There's **"To the moon, Alice!"**, but that's a [cultural reference](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Honeymooners) more than English.

Comment: Closest thing might be the noun ''lunar landing'', but there is not a specific verb.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: No. That verb does not exist.

There's a lot of fun verbs in other languages that don't exist in English. For example "temblar" in Spanish means "to tremble" literally, but it is used as "to earthquake". So in Spanish you can literally say "It earthquaked yesterday"

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

English doesn't tend to make up new words for situations as specific as this one. That is, we have the verb *to land* and we have the noun *the moon*. Since we have both of those, when we come to a point in time where moon landings are something to discuss, we don't create a new verb. We simply combine the words we already have: *to land on the moon*.

I have a feeling from some questions asked here in the past that verbs with specific meanings are common in some other languages. But English doesn't tend to do this. We like the familiar words, I suppose. (Though we do have a habit of turning nouns into informal verbs!)

Comment: I agree that we don't typically make up new verbs, but it's worth noting that the term [_lunar landing_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lunar-landing) did enter the vernacular.